# Repeat / "include" div in the same document

Tags: php, html, css, include

I'm working on a website in which part of the content (an "info" table that is different in every page) needs to be in a different div altogether in the responsive mode vs desktop mode.

I'm looking for a way in which I can repeat this div without having to copy it and paste it twice in every page. A bit like you'd have an php include query but without having a file specifically for it.

Is there a way to assign an ID / name for a part of the content on the same page and then "calling" it again?

EDIT with more info:

Basically every page has a floating div with information (it's a portfolio for an artist made by a friend that I've been asked to make responsive)

In the desktop version that info DIV is simply

```
 #infodiv {
    z-index:99;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    right:0px;
    width:250px;
    height:310px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #999;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

For the responsive version I am including a navbar that will go over the entire page when a button is clicked (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_full)

The only way I've found to do this is to have #infodivdesktop that is hidden when accessing the website via mobile and to have the above navbar in the mobile version. Thus repeating the content of the div twice..

Comment: From how I understand the question, the answer is yes. However, if you need more details, please be more specific in the question, i.e. what you tried that didn't work as intended.

Comment: HTML is just a static document, if you don't want to use PHP or some JavaScript to duplicate the HTML element you're out of luck I guess.

Comment: I'm using php for the website so it is definitely a possibility, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: I'm editing my post to include some more info!

Comment: Is your question really how the server side can know it's a mobile or desktop device so you can send it different information, depending?

Comment: No, it is "really" actually not. I'm working with media queries but the content needs to be in a different div altogether.